# java rotation, rotates and moves

Tags: java, rotation

Here is the code for java class rotation, the class is part of draw package the ball rotates and moves towards left how is it possible to stabilize it and make it rotate about co ordinates

Also is it possible to use an image instead of ball and which types of images are allowed, gif, jpeg or png

```
package draw;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Rotation extends java.applet.Applet {

final static int BALL_RADIUS = 45;

BufferedImage ball = null;

public void init()
{
    ball = new BufferedImage(BALL_RADIUS, BALL_RADIUS, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics ballG = ball.getGraphics();   

    ballG.setColor(Color.white);

    for(int i=-20;i<=0;i++)
    {
     ballG.drawOval(i, i, BALL_RADIUS + ((-i)*2), BALL_RADIUS + ((-i)*2));                    
    }
}   

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    float angle = 0;
    double speed =  0.1;
    int x = 140;
    int y = 140;
    for(int c=0;c<1600;c++)
    {
    float radius = 4;           
    x = (int) (x + Math.cos(angle) * radius);
    y = (int) (y + Math.sin(angle) * radius);
    angle += speed;        
    g.fillRect(42, 45, getBounds().width, getBounds().height);
    g.setColor(Color.white);        
    g.drawImage(ball, x, y, this);             
    delay(25);    
}
    System.out.println("paint() done");    
}   

private void delay(int millis)
{
    try{Thread.sleep(millis);}catch(Exception ignored){}       
}
}
```

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: the question is as the ball rotates it moves towards left would want it stable or about specific co ordinates